# How to strip off a string from a string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, strip

I am writing a method that accepts a string which is only java attribute/field declaration and returns only the attribute name. e.g.:

```
private double d = 1000;
private boolean b;
private final int f = 100;
private char c = 'c';
```

so if the parameter is one of the above the method should return only d, b, f or c. How is algorithms should be implemented. I have tried to use regex to strip the word after the types but it became very complicated. Can anyone give me some clues, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    String type = str.replaceAll(".*\\s(.)\\s*=.*", "$1");
```

Comment: You might want to add a `[\\s]*` to handle the case where there's no space (or extra space) between the variable name and assignment: `String type = declaration.replaceAll(".* (.)[\\s]*=.*", "$1");`

Comment: I agree, that's better, added

Comment: Your code will fail on this string, right? `String a = "int b = 10";`. It will print `b` instead of `a`. Sneaky, but possible ;). You should use lazy on the first Kleene star, and I think you should cater the case where the variable name could be more than one characters: `".*?\\s+(\\S+)\\s*=.*"`

Answer (score 1):

You can take the string before the equal sign without regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        String theString = sc.nextLine();
        String left = theString.split("=")[0].trim(); // Split into variable part and value part
        int lastSpace = left.lastIndexOf(" "); // there must be a space before a variable declaration, take the index
        String variableName = left.substring(lastSpace+1); // take the variable name
        System.out.println(variableName);
    }
}
```

If you're implementing this on Python, it's much easier:

```
the_string = 'private double d = 1000;'
print the_string.split('=',1)[0].strip().rsplit(' ',1)[1]
```